# How to use g:message from Javascript

Tags: javascript, grails, internationalization

There are some messages coming from a Javascript file to a GSP page. How can I implement g:message in a Javascript page?

For example:

```
if ($('#name').val() == "") {
    $('#nameStatus').show();
    $('#nameStatus').html('<font color=red>Company Name can not be blank</font>');
    return false;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this kind of syntax :

```
function foo() {
    return "${message(code:'my.message.code')}";
}
```

Comment: That would work if your javascript is within your GSP file, but if you are including a .js file it won't work afaik

Comment: @omarello According to the following source it's possible to render .js files from a controller: https://gist.github.com/sergiomichels/6063861

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to be able to use the output from g:message in your javascript.

There is a very helpful blog post which talks about how to use g:createLink in a similar way that you want, so you can easily adapt it to use g:message as well. Check out the [post here](http://blogs.bytecode.com.au/glen/2011/07/04/using-grails-links-from-javascript-a-micropattern.html), there is some useful info in the comments as well.

The idea is to create javascript objects in your GSP file; which should be defined before including your javascript file; and then just access those global objects in your js code.

**Edit:**

You might also be interested in the [GSParse Plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/gsp-arse). I haven't tried it my self but I think it accomplishes what you are looking for as well.