# Dynamic use of g:message in Javascript

Tags: javascript, grails

is there an easy way to use the g:message functionality in a dynamic way in Javascript, e.g.

```
function get_i18n( myAttr ) {

   return "${message(code:'" + myAttr + "')} ";

}
```

so that I can perform the function call

```
pl_get_i18n( "xyz" )
```

for the predefined i18 attribute xzy ?

Like here, but dynamic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8296812/1779814

PS: The JS code is included in the GSP file.

Comment: Javascript gets executed within the client browser, at the time it's called, where GSP/tag libraries get executed when the page is rendered by the server. You can not mix the two in this manner. By the time your javascript executes the server has already rendered the page and processed the `message` tag. In order to do this you will need to make a controller that takes a message code as a parameter and returns the value, accessing it via ajax from your javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is "no". GSP tags can only be executed on the server-side, not by the browser (i.e. JavaScript).

However, I would expect there is at least one Grails plugin that does the following:

- creates a JavaScript object containing the messages defined in your `messages*.properties` file(s)
- provides a JavaScript function that enables you to resolve messages from this object

So although it's not possible to execute GSP tags in the browser, it doesn't seem terribly difficult to provide equivalent functionality in JavaScript. I would be amazed if there isn't already a Grails plugin that does this.

Comment: A bit like this: http://sergiosmind.wordpress.com/2013/07/25/getting-all-i18n-messages-in-javascript/

Comment: JAWR used to do something like this, but someone was saying recently that it seems to be abandoned. But writing all of the strings at once is  efficient, and even more so if you configure caching

Comment: @BurtBeckwith I can't see anything in the source/docs of the JAWR plugin that suggests it does this, but you may be right. Anyhow, the JAWR plugin doesn't seem to work with either the resources or assets-pipeline plugin so probably not of much use to most Grails 2.X apps

Comment: It might not be a part of the plugin, or perhaps removed, but most likely just an omission in the plugin docs. It's described for the JAWR library here: https://jawr.java.net/docs/messages_gen.html

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very simplistic example of how you can use AJAX to fetch a message code from the server.

```
// AjaxMessageController.groovy
package example

import grails.converters.JSON

class AjaxMessageController {
    def index() {
        render [message: message(code: param.code)] as JSON
    }
}
```

Then within your page you can just use an ajax call (jQuery based) in this example to look up a message code:

```
var someMessageCode = 'something.you.want';
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '${createLinK(controller: "ajaxMessage", action: "index"}',
    data: {code: someMessageCode},
    success: function(data) {
        window.alert(data.message);
    }
});
```

Comment: I understand that you're not claiming this code to be production grade, but just in case anyone thinks otherwise: using a separate AJAX request to retrieve each message is a really bad idea from a performance point-of-view. All the messages should be downloaded in a single request and cached by the browser. Also, the implementation above does not allow values to be substituted into messages with arguments.

Comment: That depends. If you only have a small subset of message codes that are rarely used if at all then this may in fact be the best production ready approach. However, I fully agree that this is a terrible approach for any site that uses message codes in nominal manner. Thank you for pointing this out specifically for future viewers of this answer. (Up vote for your answer and now your comment too)